# Subclassing UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UIViewController` which I placed `UISegmenetedControl` with 2 options and beneath I have a `UIView` which acts as a container for putting my custom `UIView` (that is actually a `UITableView`). When switching between segments I would like to switch between 2 different `UITableViews.`

My problem is with the `UITableView.` 
I have created a custom `UIView` class with `.xib` and inside I put a `UITableView` and I'm able to populate the data into the table and see it correctly.

The problem is with the scrolling, it doesn't react to vertical scrolling at all!

Here is how I created the `UIView` with its table.

`.h` file

```
@interface LeaderboardTableView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *myScore;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *players;


- (id)initWithBoardType:(LeaderboardType)boardType myScore:(NSDictionary*)myScore leaderboardData:(NSArray*)data;

@end
```

.m file

```
@implementation LeaderboardTableView

- (id)initWithBoardType:(LeaderboardType)boardType myScore:(NSDictionary*)myScore leaderboardData:(NSArray*)data {

    self = [super init];
    if(self) {

        _players = data;
        _myScore = myScore;
        _boardType = boardType;

        self.tableView.delegate = self;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    }

    return self;

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self) {
        [self setup];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setup {

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LeaderboardTableView" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.view];
}
```

Here is my .XIB

[image]

What am I doing wrong?? I suspect that my `UITableView` resides in `UIView` and that's why I can't scroll but I cannot figure out how to solve this.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know how do you instantiat your class in your code, but their is something strange : you load an interface with `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` but you don't use it...

Comment: I'm pretty new to iOS developing I might do things wrong, could you tell me how would you fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you use `initWithBoardType:myScore:leaderboardData:` to instantiate your view, try to change :

```
self = [super init];
```

by

```
self = [self initWithNibName:@"LeaderboardTableView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

in this method.

But it's not sure that it will fix your scrolling problem. It looks like if there were a "invisible" view over your table.
 Let me know how you display your view.

Comment: I might be wrong, but only UIViewController has 'InitWithNibName' method.

Could it be that because my UITableView is in UIView causes my scrolling problem?? (look at the screenshot I've attached).

Comment: There is no problem in your view hierarchy. UItableView inherits of UIView. So you can add it as a subview of any view. Now, if your `LeaderboardTableView` class inherit of UIViewController instead of UIView, you will be able to call `initWithNibName`. Then just change in you .xib file the conection of the outlet `view` and let it be `file's Owner` instead of `Leaderboard Table View`

Comment: I need to put LeaderboardTableView inside another ViewController which is the host of this table, is it possible to put ViewController inside ViewController?

Comment: Sure. When you instantiate your `LeaderboardTableView` (let name it ltv) you then have access to property `ltv.view`. Your class `LeaderboardTableView` will keep managing the table delegate method, but its view will be displayed in another controller's view. Remember that `A view controller manages a set of views that make up a portion of your app’s user interface.` A view controller is not a displayable element, but its view is. You can display a controller's view in whatever view you want (exept its own view and subviews of course)

Comment: so in this case I can create a UITableViewController instead of UIViewController and it will even ease populating cells into it.

Answer (score 1):

A better idea would be to use one table view and switch out the data source for each different UISegmentedControl tap.

Comment: Interesting!

How do you do this??

Comment: I would set up enumeration constants representing each button in the segmented control, and when the user taps a button set an instance variable to store the corresponding enumeration constant value. Then in the datasource methods use a switch statement to test the value of that instance variable, and return the appropriate data source information

Comment: Nice, most of what you suggested I already have.
I will give it a try...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to resolve this problem with a lot of help from zbMax !

Eventually I made my custom Table to subclass UITableViewController with XIB. I implemented all the logic of populating cells and embedded this TableView in my parent view controller, this way I could switch between 2 Views of tables.